# Can not connect to DB in PhpStorm

Tags: database, phpstorm

Here is how I'm trying to connect to the DB:

[image]

Here is everything I know about DB:

```
define( 'DB_NAME', 'wordpress' );
define( 'DB_USER', 'wordpress' );
define( 'DB_PASSWORD', 'wordpress' );
define( 'DB_HOST', 'database' );
```

And I'm getting this error when I m pressing test connection
`[08000][-1] Could not connect to address=(host=database)(port=3306)(type=master) : Socket fail to connect to host:database, port:3306. database java.net.UnknownHostException: database.`

Any suggestions please?

Comment: On what host have you installed the database? If it is inside a virtual or containerized environment, you might rather want to connect to localhost, or point `database` to an IP in your `/etc/hosts/`  file.

Comment: Thank you @DanielW. I will try that